# How get variable value using HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a little check in model:

```
class Customers < ActiveRecord::Base
  def check_user_name(name, email)
    name = Customers.where(:name => name)
    email = Customers.where(:email => email)
    if name && email    
      @answer = 'Question was send to us. Thank you.'
    else 
      @answer = 'ERROR, no such name or email.'    
    end
  end 
end
```

and view (haml file):

```
=@answer
```

But on page is no text...empty....please, explain me WHY ?)

Comment: do you make a difference between controller and model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instance variables in your model are not accessible from your view.

Instance variables in your *controller* are how you pass data to your view.

Try just returning the string from your model method, and then assigning it to the variable `@answer` in your controller. eg. `@answer = cust.check_user_name(params[:name], params[:email])`

Comment: here is my controller:
`class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def ask
    
  end
  
  def check_user
    cust = Customers.new
    cust.check_user_name(params[:name], params[:email])    
  end
  
end`

Comment: thank you very much.
Fix in controller:
@answer = cust.check_user_name(params[:name], params[:email])
Fix in model:
return 'Question was send to us. Thank you.'
or return somthig else text

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Customers < ActiveRecord::Base #why this model plural?
  def check_user_name(name, email)
    result = {}
    result[:name] = where(:name => name)
    result[:email] = where(:email => email)
  end
end

class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  result = Customers.check_user_name(name, email)
  if result[:name].present? && result[:email].present?
      @answer = 'Question was send to us. Thank you.'
    else 
      @answer = 'ERROR, no such name or email.'    
    end
end

 =@answer
```

all instance variables in controller are passed into views